# How to see intermediate results from tuning in mlr in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mlr

Is it possible to see results for tuning rounds when using `mlr` and `parallelMap` and parallelizing at the `mlr.tuneParams` level?

When I tune in serial, I see the results (hyperparameters, measures) in the Console for each combination of hyperparameters as CV finishes. Thus, if I kill a job before the tuneParams result saves, I still have some results.

When I tune in parallel, I do not know how to see intermediate results in the result that a job is terminated. Is it possible to create a log file that shows results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with *parallelMap*. In the background, `mclapply()` (multicore) or `clusterMap()` (socket) are called which do not allow progress output of workers.

You might want to try out [mlr3](https://mlr3.mlr-org.com) which relies on the *future* package for parallelization.
With this you can select different parallel backends which might help to achieve what you want.

```r
library("mlr")
#> Loading required package: ParamHelpers
library("parallelMap")

discrete_ps <- makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("C", values = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)),
  makeDiscreteParam("sigma", values = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0))
)
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 5)
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2L)

# socket mode ------------------------------------------------------------------

parallelStartSocket(2, level = "mlr.tuneParams")
#> Starting parallelization in mode=socket with cpus=2.
res <- tuneParams("classif.ksvm",
  task = iris.task, resampling = rdesc,
  par.set = discrete_ps, control = ctrl, show.info = TRUE
)
#> [Tune] Started tuning learner classif.ksvm for parameter set:
#>           Type len Def      Constr Req Tunable Trafo
#> C     discrete   -   - 0.5,1,1.5,2   -    TRUE     -
#> sigma discrete   -   - 0.5,1,1.5,2   -    TRUE     -
#> With control class: TuneControlRandom
#> Imputation value: 1
#> Exporting objects to slaves for mode socket: .mlr.slave.options
#> Mapping in parallel: mode = socket; level = mlr.tuneParams; cpus = 2; elements = 5.
#> [Tune] Result: C=2; sigma=0.5 : mmce.test.mean=0.0600000
parallelStop()
#> Stopped parallelization. All cleaned up.

# sequential -------------------------------------------------------------------

res <- tuneParams("classif.ksvm",
  task = iris.task, resampling = rdesc,
  par.set = discrete_ps, control = ctrl, show.info = TRUE
)
#> [Tune] Started tuning learner classif.ksvm for parameter set:
#>           Type len Def      Constr Req Tunable Trafo
#> C     discrete   -   - 0.5,1,1.5,2   -    TRUE     -
#> sigma discrete   -   - 0.5,1,1.5,2   -    TRUE     -
#> With control class: TuneControlRandom
#> Imputation value: 1
#> [Tune-x] 1: C=1.5; sigma=1.5
#> [Tune-y] 1: mmce.test.mean=0.0466667; time: 0.0 min
#> [Tune-x] 2: C=0.5; sigma=1.5
#> [Tune-y] 2: mmce.test.mean=0.0600000; time: 0.0 min
#> [Tune-x] 3: C=0.5; sigma=1.5
#> [Tune-y] 3: mmce.test.mean=0.0600000; time: 0.0 min
#> [Tune-x] 4: C=1; sigma=2
#> [Tune-y] 4: mmce.test.mean=0.0466667; time: 0.0 min
#> [Tune-x] 5: C=1; sigma=2
#> [Tune-y] 5: mmce.test.mean=0.0466667; time: 0.0 min
#> [Tune] Result: C=1; sigma=2 : mmce.test.mean=0.0466667

# multicore --------------------------------------------------------------------

parallelStartMulticore(2, level = "mlr.tuneParams")
#> Starting parallelization in mode=multicore with cpus=2.
res <- tuneParams("classif.ksvm",
  task = iris.task, resampling = rdesc,
  par.set = discrete_ps, control = ctrl, show.info = TRUE
)
#> [Tune] Started tuning learner classif.ksvm for parameter set:
#>           Type len Def      Constr Req Tunable Trafo
#> C     discrete   -   - 0.5,1,1.5,2   -    TRUE     -
#> sigma discrete   -   - 0.5,1,1.5,2   -    TRUE     -
#> With control class: TuneControlRandom
#> Imputation value: 1
#> Mapping in parallel: mode = multicore; level = mlr.tuneParams; cpus = 2; elements = 5.
#> [Tune] Result: C=2; sigma=1.5 : mmce.test.mean=0.0466667
parallelStop()
#> Stopped parallelization. All cleaned up.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>